# Autofac An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration

Tags: autofac

I have inherited a .NET project which keeps throwing Autofac errors but I'm not sure what this error message is telling me. Any help would be appreciated?

```
An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. 
Registration: 
Activator = ImplementationResourceRepository (ReflectionActivator), 
Services = [Interfaces.IImplementationResourceRepository], 
Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, 
Sharing = None, 
Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'CCES.Repositories.ImplementationResourceRepository' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Interfaces.IRepository repository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Interfaces.IRepository)'. (See inner exception for details.)
```

Comment: (side note) If any answers on your questions (*I see you have asked questions in the past*) do answer your question please take the time to mark them as "the answer" using the checkmark on the left side of the answer (*just click it, it will turn green*). This helps other identify the proper fix and those that took the time to help you also very much appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Type `ImplementationResourceRepository` has a constructor that takes an instance that implements `Interfaces.IRepository` in it's constructor but no types were registered as `Interfaces.IRepository`. You need to register a type that implementats `Interfaces.IRepository` as that interface with Autofac.

Something similar to this:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<Implementations.Repository>()
        .As<Interfaces.IRepository>()
        .InstancePerDependency();
}
```